# Multiple read call of a socket fd with O_NONBLOCK set fails

Tags: c, linux, sockets, select, file-descriptor

I am using `select()`, and `NONBLOCKING` connection fd to accept connections and handle input and output. I am having some issue handling large data transfer of more than the buffer size. So for example here:

```
readCount = 1;
while(readCount > 0)
{
    // clear t_input to read new data from the fd
    memset(t_input, 0, CLIENT_INPUT_BUFF_LEN);

    // read data from the client connectionFd and since t_input is 1024 only
    // read that much
    readCount = read(iter->connectionFd, t_input, 1024);
    printf("<<< %d - %s >>> \n", errno, strerror(errno));

    if(readCount == -1)
    {
        if( errno == EAGAIN) 
            break;
    }

    iter->AppendInputData(t_input, readCount);
}
```

This doesn't work for large data. So when I transfer data that is less than `1024`, The first `read` call successfully finishes and data is copied in the `AppendInputData` call. Since it's in a loop, the second `read` call returns `-1`, and set's `errno` to `EAGAIN` which then breaks the loop - all is good for this case.

However, in the case of larger than `1024` data, the second read calls fails again and `errno` is set to `EAGAIN`. The weird thing is, in debug mode, I don't see this behavior and the second or third `read` call returns fine and all data is collected. Can someone explain what might be happening?

Comment: where is your select() call ? Getting EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK is normal and expected, it means your non-blocking read() call would have blocked. You should return to doing select() and read more when select() says you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something more like this instead:

```
do
{
    // read data from the client connectionFd and since t_input is 1024 only read that much
    readCount = read(iter->connectionFd, t_input, 1024);

    if (readCount == -1)
    {
        if (errno == EAGAIN) 
        {
            fd_set fd;
            FD_ZERO(&fd);
            FD_SET(iter->connectionFd, &fd);

            timeval tv;
            tv.tv_sec = 5;
            tv.tv_usec = 0;

            readCount = select(iter->connectionFd+1, &fd, NULL, NULL, &tv);
            if (readCount == 1)
                continue;

            if (readCount == 0)
            {
                printf("<<< timeout >>> \n");
                break;
            }
        }

        printf("<<< %d - %s >>> \n", errno, strerror(errno));
        break;
    }

    if (readCount == 0)
    {
        printf("<<< disconnect >>> \n");
        break;
    }

    iter->AppendInputData(t_input, readCount);
}
while (true);
```

Comment: the file flag is set to `NONBLOCKING`, so I don't know providing a timeout would help.

Comment: @ArmenB. I suggest you look up what select() actually does.

Comment: @ArmenB.: It is specifically because of `NONBLOCKING` that I added the timeout logic.  Transmission speeds vary.  When `read()` reports `EAGAIN`, it simply means there is not a single byte available *at that very moment*. In case the network hiccupped momentarily, you can give the loop a few extra seconds to check if a new byte arrives, so you don't have to break the loop prematurely. If you don't receive even 2 bytes within 5 seconds, there is good chance the client has stopped sending data. Of course, you can use whatever timeout is meaningful to your code.

Answer (score 2):

It's all timing. You can't assume that all the data will arrive continuously and be available whenever you call read(), or that when EAGAIN occurs that's the end of it forever. It is customary to call select() to tell you when data is available to read.

You get a different behaviour in debug mode because you're altering the timing.

Comment: So how can I know when a client has finished sending all it's data. I am using an event based system which I want to raise an even when a client receives all data. How do browsers know when a web servers has finished sending all the content of the page?

Comment: TCP is a byte stream, it has no concept of message boundaries. You have to implement that logic in your communication protocol. The client has to either 1) first send a number/header that says how many data bytes are being sent, and then send the actual data; or 2) send a unique terminator after sending the data, where the terminator does not appear in the data.  You can read the size value first and keep reading until you have received that many bytes, or keep reading until you encounter the terminator. Whichever method fits your protocol.

Comment: HTTP defines a set of rules for how end-of-message is determined.  See [RFC 2616 Section 4](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4). First the message headers are sent, which are terminated by a blank line, then the headers describe how the rest of the data is formatted. Multiple formats are supported, each with a different way to detect end-of-data.

Comment: @ArmenB. You can't use EAGAIN as a message boundary.